# MS Access updating records with same values in all rows in table

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

i am trying to update records using MS Access database but all records are getting updated with same values..i tried same coding with sql server with bit modification and this coding works perfectly with sql server...whats the problem with MS Access ?
here is  my code :

```
 Try

 con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
 con.Open()

 Dim cb As String = "update ExtraServices set [Item]=?, [Quantity]=?,[UnitPrice]=?, [TotalPrice]=? where [HostelerID]=? and [Servicedate]=?"
 Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(cb, con)
 cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@item", OleDbType.VarChar, 150, "Item"))
 cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@quantity", OleDbType.Integer, 6, "Quantity"))
 cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@unitprice", OleDbType.Integer, 6, "UnitPrice"))
 cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@total", OleDbType.Integer, 6, "TotalPrice"))
 cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@hostelerID", OleDbType.VarChar, 20, "HostelerID"))
 cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ServiceDate", OleDbType.Date, 30, "ServiceDate"))
 ' Prepare command for repeated execution
 cmd.Prepare()
 ' Data to be inserted
 For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
     If Not row.IsNewRow Then
         cmd.Parameters("@item").Value = row.Cells(0).Value
         cmd.Parameters("@quantity").Value = row.Cells(1).Value
         cmd.Parameters("@unitprice").Value = row.Cells(2).Value
         cmd.Parameters("@total").Value = row.Cells(3).Value
         cmd.Parameters("@HostelerID").Value = cmbHostelerID.Text
         cmd.Parameters("@ServiceDate").Value = dtpServiceDate.Text
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
     End If
 Next
 con.Close()
 MessageBox.Show("Successfully updated", "Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
 btnUpdate_record.Enabled = False
 Catch ex As Exception
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
 End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *other @Steve* is right.  In every loop, you tell the database to update ALL records

```
WHERE HostelerID = cmbHostelerID.Text AND ServiceDate = dtpServiceDate.Text
```

This does not change from one iteration to the next so when you are done looping, whatever the last values were for Item, Quantity, UnitPrice and TotalPrice are applied to all record that match that criteria.

Does your **ExtraServices** table have a primary key? Is so, that should be used for your update SQL.

If this works with MSSQL (with bit modification), what is the modification?

If this isn't helpful (not the solution) then provide some more info. Sample data helps. Example of what you expect to happen. What are you trying to do here. We can't tell from the code but we can tell it is wrong.  Help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

The parameters used for the WHERE clause are always the same. So you query updates always the same records (and you end your loop updating the same set of records with the values from the last row from the grid)

```
     cmd.Parameters("@HostelerID").Value = cmbHostelerID.Text   ' <- same for every row
     cmd.Parameters("@ServiceDate").Value = dtpServiceDate.Text
```

Comment: but i am updating others field...this query worked perfectly with sql server with bit modification..whats wrong with MS access ?

Comment: how can i solve this problem ? i am updating records using datagridview

Comment: How can i update datagridview values of other fields with updated values in datagridview....

Comment: please some one help on this...its very urgent